# ReCaptcha not valid + CodeIgniter Form helper = form data lost

Tags: forms, validation, codeigniter, captcha, recaptcha

Here is a strange behavior when I use codeIgniter and ReCaptcha.

I used ReCaptcha as a simple application/helper. The only change I have made is rename the API "recaptcha_helper.php" and I added

```
if(!defined('RECAPTCHA")){ 
   define('RECAPTCHA',true);
   [API code]
}
```

When posting data to my controller the result is... not as expected.

```
ReCaptcha valid / form valid = works fine!
ReCaptcha valid / form not valid = works fine!
ReCaptcha not valid / form valid = all form data lost
ReCaptcha not valid / form not valid = all form data lost + validation lost
```

Also I use "set_value('input_name')" like all other websites I've made. It used to work like a charm until today when I put a recaptcha in a form.

Here is the controller :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Register extends MY_Controller {


    var $form_rules = array(    
                        array(
                            'field' => 'user_first_name',
                            'label' => 'Prénom ',
                            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_lenght[50]|xss_clean'),
                        array(
                            'field' => 'user_last_name',
                            'label' => 'Nom ',
                            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_lenght[50]|xss_clean'),
                        array(
                            'field' => 'user_email',
                            'label' => 'Courriel ',
                            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_lenght[100]|valid_email|xss_clean'),
                        array(
                            'field' => 'user_email_confirm',
                            'label' => 'Confirmation du courriel ',
                            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_lenght[100]|matches[user_email]|xss_clean'));

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function register(){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->form_rules);

        // RECAPTCHA STUFF
        $this->load->helper('recaptcha');
        $publickey = "****";
        $privatekey = "****";
        # the response from reCAPTCHA
        $resp = null;
        # the error code from reCAPTCHA, if any
        $error = null;

        if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0){
            $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
            if ($resp->is_valid) {
                if($this->form_validation->run()){
                    $new_data = array(  'user_first_name' => $_POST['user_first_name'],
                                        'user_last_name' => $_POST['user_last_name'],
                                        'user_email' => $_POST['user_email']);
                    $this->db->insert('user', $new_data);
                    $new_user_id = $this->db->insert_id();
                    $this->load->view('header');
                    $this->load->view('sent');
                    $this->load->view('footer');
                    return;
                }
            }else{
                 $error = $resp->error;
            }
            $data = $_POST;
        }

        $data['recaptcha'] = recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('inscription_form', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

And here is the form

```
<div id="inscription">        
    <?php echo form_open(); ?>
        <p>
            <label for="user_first_name">Pr&eacute;nom *</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_first_name" value="<?php echo set_value('user_first_name'); ?>" maxlength="50" />
            <?php echo form_error('user_first_name'); ?>
        </p>
        <p class="clear">
            <label for="user_last_name">Nom *</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_last_name" value="<?php echo set_value('user_last_name'); ?>" maxlength="50" />
            <?php echo form_error('user_last_name'); ?>
        </p>
        <p class="clear">
            <label for="user_email">Courriel *</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_email" value="<?php echo set_value('user_email'); ?>" maxlength="100" />
            <?php echo form_error('user_email'); ?>
        </p>
        <p class="clear">
            <label for="user_email_confirm">Confirmation du courriel *</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_email_confirm" value="<?php echo set_value('user_email_confirm'); ?>" maxlength="100" />
            <?php echo form_error('user_email_confirm'); ?>
       </p>
       <div class="clear"></div>
        <div><?php echo $recaptcha; ?></div>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Envoyer"/></p>
        <p class="clear">* Tous les champs de ce formulaire sont requis.</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Also I use ReCaptcha version 1.11

Comment: you need to post your view + controller form to see what is going on

Comment: Sure. I added the code in the question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to repopulate the form you **must** run the form_validation command.

But your problem is that in your code, if the reCaptcha fails, you never run the validation, and therefore there is nothing to fill in the form again (because it never actually gets to the validation).

So change your code around, and run the form validation first. If the form validation returns true, then check the captcha.

```
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0){
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
         if($this->form_validation->run()) 
          {
            if ($resp->is_valid) 
            {
                $new_data = array(  'user_first_name' => $_POST['user_first_name'],
                                    'user_last_name' => $_POST['user_last_name'],
                                    'user_email' => $_POST['user_email']);
                $this->db->insert('user', $new_data);
                $new_user_id = $this->db->insert_id();
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('sent');
                $this->load->view('footer');
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                  $error = $resp->error;
            }
        }
        $data = $_POST;
    }
```

One thing - to improve your code - make your reCaptcha ($resp->is_valid) a callback method instead - then you can actually run the captcha as part of the form validation, rather than a seperate method.

[See here for callbacks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)

```
public function _recaptcha_check($str)
    {
              $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($str,
                                    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
          if ( ! $resp->is_valid)
          {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('_recaptcha_check', 'Your reCaptcha was wrong!');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

and set this where you set the rules (note the double "_" for the callback name)

```
array(
                            'field' => 'recaptcha_response_field',
                            'label' => 'Recaptcha',
                            'rules' => 'required|callback__recaptcha_check'),
```

Comment: This is finally not a bug but a code 14 :P Of course validation does not runs when captcha isn't valid. I also added recaptcha validation as part of my form_validation. Thanks Laurencei for your clear answer!

Comment: For the record, the call to `recaptcha_get_answer` in the callback example is wrong - `$str` should be the last parameter, as it is the user input, and you should keep using your private key as the first parameter. It works perfectly then ! To access the error message related to the captcha in your view, just use `form_error('recaptcha_response_field');`.